Help to solve a complicated couple of second ODE analytically
I have been for some time now try to analytically solve the following couple of ODE:
  equ1[t_]:= (640 y[t]+(2+3 t) (4+6 t)^(1/3) (-3 (2+3 t)^2 (4 2^(1/3)+
   6 (2+3  t)^(1/3)+9 t (2+3 t)^(1/3)) f[t]+
    2 2^(1/3) (72 y[t]+5 (2+3 t)^3 f'[t]))/(32 (2+3 t)^2)


 equ2[t_]:= 3/32 (128/(2+3 t)^2-264 2^(2/3) (2+3 t)^(1/3)+
    4 k^2 (2+3 t)^2-3 (4+6 t)^(1/3) (4 (2+3 t)^(1/3)+
    3 t (8 2^(1/3)+4 (2+3 t)^(1/3)+3 t (2+3 t)^(1/3)))) f[t]+
   (k^2+(9 (-272+24 t+2^(2/3) (2+3 t)^(7/3)))/(2 (2+3 t)^3)) y[t]+
(3 (f'[t])/(2+3 t)`

I try to solve for y and f which are functions in two variables t and k. The initial conditions are arbitrary.
I tried to use:
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{equ2[t] == 0, equ1[t] == y''[t], y[0] == 0.1, y'[0] == 0.1, f[0] == 1}, y[t], {t, 0, 3}]
That returns the same function.
sol = DSolve[{equ2[t] == 0, equ1[t] == y''[t], y[0] == 0.1,y'[0] == 0.1, f[0] == 1}, y, t] // FullSimplify;
That returns an error. So it will be so appreciated if there is an appropriate way to find the analytic solution.

Your ODE system does contains two functions and you also have to specify that in DSolve or AsymptoticDSolveValue (replace the y[t] in AsymptoticDSolveValue[{...}, y[t], {...}] with {y[t], f[t]} such that Mathematica solves for both functions):
equ1[t_]:= (640 y[t]+(2+3 t) (4+6 t)^(1/3) (-3 (2+3 t)^2 (4 2^(1/3)+
    6 (2+3  t)^(1/3)+9 t (2+3 t)^(1/3)) f[t]+
    2 2^(1/3) (72 y[t]+5 (2+3 t)^3 f'[t]))/(32 (2+3 t)^2);

equ2[t_]:= 3/32 (128/(2+3 t)^2-264 2^(2/3) (2+3 t)^(1/3)+
    4 k^2 (2+3 t)^2-3 (4+6 t)^(1/3) (4 (2+3 t)^(1/3)+
    3 t (8 2^(1/3)+4 (2+3 t)^(1/3)+3 t (2+3 t)^(1/3)))) f[t]+
   (k^2+(9 (-272+24 t+2^(2/3) (2+3 t)^(7/3)))/(2 (2+3 t)^3)) y[t]+
(3 (f'[t])/(2+3 t);

AsymptoticDSolveValue[{equ2[t] == 0, equ1[t] == y''[t],
    y[0] == 0.1, y'[0] == 0.1, f[0] == 1}, {y[t], f[t]}, {t, 0, 3}]


The first solution is your function y[t] and the second solution is f[t]. You can change the order by simply switching of y[t] and f[t] in AsymptoticDSolveValue[{...}, {y[t], f[t]}, {...}].
You can find more informatons and example in the documentation of AsymptoticDSolveValue > Scope > Systems of ODEs.

Another problem is that if $y$ and $f$ depend on two variables ($t$ and $k$), but you stated that they only depend on one ($t$). In addition, (f^\[Prime]) is not defined.

Nice idea (+1)! I think k is a parameter ( not a variable)

@KevinDietrich.. thanks so much for your answer, so it's easy like that , just adding y[t]. About k variable, I think after getting the solution, one can define say : sol1[k_,t_] := sol[[1]] and sol2[k_,t_] := sol[[2]], since at last the AsymptoticDSolveValue solution is given in terms of t and k.
